# Show details in TreeView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, treeview

Is it possible to show (custom) details in a WPF TreeView?

I want to display all services of my computer and have Description, Status, etc. right next to it and be able to order it when expanded. Is it possible to achieve that?

I'm creating the tree programmatically, this is what I have so far:

```
    public void LoadServices(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeView.Items.Clear();
        List<string> computers = new List<string> { Environment.MachineName, Environment.MachineName };
        foreach (string computer in computers)
        {
            TreeViewItem CurrComputer = new TreeViewItem { Header = computer };
            TreeView.Items.Add(CurrComputer);
            Services = ServiceController.GetServices();

            foreach (ServiceController tempService in Services)
            {
                TreeViewItem newService = new TreeViewItem
                {
                    Header = tempService.DisplayName
                };
                CurrComputer.Items.Add(newService);
            }
        }
    }
```

/edit: One solution I can think of is placing a list view right next to it, and map it from the treeview to the list view. But thats not very smooth and also means if I order by something, the treeview will not be ordered.

Comment: Have you ever considered using MvvM? This would fit perfectly in your `ViewModel`. Then you would provide a Hierarchical Data Template for the tree view items. None of this code behind malarkey.

Comment: see my answer and please upvote if it helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the solution i am using: is suggest you to use ObservableCollection to write a minimal coding

### MainWindows.xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="zzWpfApp2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:zzWpfApp2"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid Margin="10">
        <TreeView Name="trvMenu">
            <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type MenuItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        </TreeView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

### MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Windows;

namespace zzWpfApp2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            List<string> computers = new List<string> { Environment.MachineName, Environment.MachineName };
            MenuItem root = new MenuItem() { Title = "General Menu" };

            foreach (string computer in computers)
            {
                MenuItem childItem = new MenuItem() { Title = computer };

                foreach (ServiceController tempService in ServiceController.GetServices())
                {
                    childItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = tempService.DisplayName });
                }
                root.Items.Add(childItem);
            }
            trvMenu.Items.Add(root);
        }
        public class MenuItem
        {
            public MenuItem()
            {
                this.Items = new ObservableCollection<MenuItem>();
            }

            public string Title { get; set; }

            public ObservableCollection<MenuItem> Items { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

and the result:

[image]

if you want more information just modify the loop:

```
            foreach (ServiceController tempService in ServiceController.GetServices())
            {
                MenuItem subchildItem = new MenuItem() {Title = tempService.DisplayName };                 
                childItem.Items.Add(subchildItem);
                subchildItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = tempService.Status.ToString()});
                subchildItem.Items.Add(new MenuItem() { Title = tempService.ServiceName});
            }
```

[image]